# How can i print a dictionary list in a listbox from tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am developing an application to search in a spreadsheet the open fees of some clients, save it in a dictionary and print it in the graphical interface. The code itself works perfectly, however, when the list gets too big at the end, the rest of the content is cut off. Can you tell me a way to solve it?

```py
from tkinter import *
import openpyxl

root = Tk()

def hono_aberto():
    newWindow = Toplevel()
    newWindow.title("Output")
    newWindow.geometry("400x350+375+50")

    # Opens the spreadsheet and obtains the status of the last payment.

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/temp/cobranca.xlsx')
    sheet = wb['Sheet1']

    lastCol = sheet.max_column
    # latestMonth = sheet.cell(row=1, column=lastCol).value

    # Checks the payment status of each customer.

    unpaidMembers = {}
    clients = []
    months = []
    emails = []
    for r in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
        for c in range(3, lastCol + 1):
            payment = sheet.cell(row=r, column=c).value
            if payment != 'ok':
                client = sheet.cell(row=r, column=1).value
                email = sheet.cell(row=r, column=2).value
                month = sheet.cell(row=1, column=c).value
                clients.append(client)
                months.append(month)
                emails.append(email)
                unpaidMembers[client] = email
                print('Line:', r, 'Column:', c, 'Client:', client, 'Email:', email, 'Month:', month)


    #--- LABELS ---#
    l_label1 = Label(newWindow, text="Client", font='-weight bold')
    l_label1.grid(row=1, column=1)
    l_label2 = Label(newWindow, text="Competence", font='-weight bold')
    l_label2.grid(row=1, column=2)
    l_label3 = Label(newWindow, text="E-mail", font='-weight bold')
    l_label3.grid(row=1, column=3)

    v_result1 = StringVar()
    l_cliente = Label(newWindow, textvariable=v_result1)
    l_cliente.grid(row=2, column=1)
    v_result2 = StringVar()
    l_mes = Label(newWindow, textvariable=v_result2)
    l_mes.grid(row=2, column=2)
    v_result3 = StringVar()
    l_email = Label(newWindow, textvariable=v_result3)
    l_email.grid(row=2, column=3)

    #--- OUTPUT ---#
    v_result1.set('\n'.join(clients))
    v_result2.set('\n'.join(months))
    v_result3.set('\n'.join(emails))




bt = Button(root, text='Check', command=hono_aberto)
bt.grid(row=1, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Here is a model of the spreadsheet used:https://prnt.sc/123sxpd

Comment: Create the label outside the function, and use `set()` inside only.

Comment: Use `Listbox` or `ttk.Treeview` widget (with associated `Scrollbar`) instead of multiple `Label` widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has something to do probably because the the text area isn't enough. The one thing you can do is to display like 10 or 15 client(you decide, whatever looks useful) data per page. This should be where you begin.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tkinter-application-to-switch-between-different-page-frames/

Then what you want to do is to change the displayed each time the new page button is clicked on. This should solve your problem

Comment: You are welcome please let me know on further issues